# navigationController title

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, controller

I am working on an app with a navigation controller. I know how to set the title when the view loads initially. I push a new view controller and set it's title. Now the problem is when I press the back button, the title for the original view controller is not there anymore. I tried to do...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.title = @"Some Title";
}
```

This did not set the title though. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: The title for the original controller cannot be changed :| Unless you intentionally do something with it. post some code.

Comment: So you are not setting `self.navigationController.title` to `nil` or `@""` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I have 2 view controllers...let's say A and B respectively. I set A's title in it's viewDidLoad method. Then, I push B and set B's title to something different in it's viewDidLoad method. When I press the Back button on B, B's view controller is popped and A is shown with no title.

Answer (score 42):

The UINavigationController gets the value for the title from the current UIViewController.

To set a the title for a view Controller, simply do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.title = @"Some Title";
}
```

For each of your View Controllers, including the root one.

Comment: I set the title for view controller on storyboard interface builder. but, that's not working!

Comment: Be careful using this, if you have a NavigationController embeded in a TabBarController this will set the tab title and the navigation bar title ! use `self.navigationItem setTitle` instead

Answer (score 10):

Try changing the navigation item's title.

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Some Title"];
```

Answer (score 9):

in **Swift 3**:

```
navigationItem.title = "Custom title"
```

or if you want to customize the details of the title:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
titleLabel.text = "Hello"
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Baskerville-Bold", size: 20)
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your title this way.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
```