# How to embed a view in a navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have 3 view controllers in a UITabBarController. In only one view controller I would like to place it in a navigation controller. What is the proper way of doing this so that only one view controller has a Navigation Controller? I would like `aController` to be in a navigation controller.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mController = MViewController()
        mpController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "view1", image: UIImage(named: "viewoneimage"), tag: 0)



        let inputController = InputViewController()
        inputController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Input", image: UIImage(named: "plus"), tag: 1)

        let aController = ATableViewController()
        aController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "custom", image: UIImage(named: "person.fill"), tag: 2)
        let navController = UINavigationController()
//        aController.navigationController = navController


        viewControllers = [mController, inputController, aController, navController]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `UINavigationController` as one of the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array?

Comment: Two things. First, you *do not* embed views in a `UINavigationController`, you embed view controllers. Second, if you wish to embed a `UINavigationController` in a view, try making it a child VC to that view's VC.

Comment: @dfd I meant view controllers my bad.

Comment: @Rudedog I did but it just shows a blank View controller. How do I add it to an existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must embend your `UIViewController` inside the `Navigation Controllers` and initialize your tab menu with your `Navigation Controllers`.

Also for each tab you will have different `Navigation Controller`

Your code should look like that.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mController = MViewController()
        mpController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "view1", image: UIImage(named: "viewoneimage"), tag: 0)
        let inputController = InputViewController()
        inputController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Input", image: UIImage(named: "plus"), tag: 1)
        let aController = ATableViewController()
        aController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "custom", image: UIImage(named: "person.fill"), tag: 2)
        let navMController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mpController)
        let navInputController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: inputController)
        let navaController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aController)
        viewControllers = [navMController, navInputController, navaController]
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! How do I set the title of the navigation controller?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643901/navigationcontroller-title